# What's wrong with this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code to render a file into another file:

```
$("#edit_topics_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".topic_form").load("/topic_form.html.erb");
        $("#edit_topics_link").hide();
});
```

This is the link:

```
<%= link_to "Add Topics", '#', :id => 'edit_topics_link' %>
```

The file topic_form.html.erb is in the same folder as the file that the link is in.

This is the error I get in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's the generated HTML? Is `/topic_form.html.erb` accessible?

Comment: the HTML is not generated because the JS is not executed due to the error. I'm not sure if I have the right path for the file?

Comment: You've provided the Ruby source for a link, not the HTML that is generated. jQuery works on parsed HTML -- it doesn't care what created it.

Comment: yea i know, I thought you were referring to the HTML from the rendered file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the backslash in `"/topic_form.html.erb"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access your view file directly?

It would probably need to be rendered by a controller first!

You could do it this way:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def topic_form
    render '/topic_form'
  end
end
```

Add the controller to your routes and you're done!